# How to prevent onCreate when application is resumed?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, oncreate

I've made a music player usim MediaPlayer. When I close the app the song keeps playing but when I resume, onCreate is called everything starts again and previous song also keeps playing. So if now I start new song, both the songs play even though there's only one MediaPlayer variable. Why is onCreate called when app is reopened. What is the way to prevent it?

**EDIT:** Note that xml file also gets reset. PLus I loose control over song playing before leaving the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SeekBar seekBar;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
ImageView imageView;
Handler handler = new Handler();
private String[] mAudioPath;
private String[] mMusicList;
static int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button ctrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.song);
    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

    //get tracks list
    mMusicList = getAudioList();
    mAudioPath = getmAudioPath();

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,mAudioPath[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mAudioPath[position]);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                ctrl.setText("║");
                try {
                    byte[] art;
                    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(mAudioPath[position]);
                    art = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
                    Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(songImage);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    byte[] art;
                    Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.default_artwork);
                    imageView.getLayoutParams().width= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(songImage);
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
});

    //Get track data
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse("android.resource://in.swapsha96.playtime/"+R.raw.song));
    String artist;
    artist = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
    if (artist == null)
        artist = "Unknown Artist";
    try {
        byte[] art;
        art = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(songImage);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,artist,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //Controls
    ctrl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                ctrl.setText("║");
            }
            else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                ctrl.setText("►");
            }
            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            handler.postDelayed(runnable,1);
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            ctrl.setText("►");
        }
    });

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
            handler.postDelayed(runnable,1);
        }
    });
}

//update seekBar
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        handler.postDelayed(this,1);
    }
};
private String[] getAudioList() {
    final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA }, null, null,
            "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

    int count = mCursor.getCount();

    String[] songs = new String[count];
    String[] mAudioPath = new String[count];
    int i = 0;
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            i++;
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    mCursor.close();

    return songs;
}private String[] getmAudioPath() {
    final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA }, null, null,
            "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

    int count = mCursor.getCount();

    String[] songs = new String[count];
    String[] path = new String[count];
    int i = 0;
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            path[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            i++;
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    mCursor.close();

    return path;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to give more information. Which `onCreate()` are you talking about?

Comment: onCreate inside MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not checking whether the mediaplayer was playing or not every time you choose a new song.

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
  {mediaplyer.stop()}
```

you need to stop it and then reset it again.
try as well to set the launch mode  in the Manifest file  of the activitg tag to be singleTask.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

My advice for you if you want yourself to get out of all this is to use a bound service. It will help you managing the mediaplayer states and will keep running in the background. This great [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764) might help.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I need 4 more points so I could comment. Anyway If he  gives more details I will edit it, and answer him.

Comment: Things is when I press back and then clicking the app, onCreate is executed because of which everything is reset and still, music is still playing. I efinitely want my app to work like other music players.

Comment: It sounds like you are creating two instances of the same activity at the same time. Have you tried to put the launchmode in the activity tag in to be singleTask.
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"

Answer (score 0):

As you know : `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` will be called when you start an Activity.So to avoid `onCreate` recall, you can use a boolean in your `onCreate` method for example `isActivityReopened` that is set to false, then set to true in the first use of `onCreate`. Here an example you can inspire from it :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
super.onCreate(bundle);
// Other stuff

if (!isActivityReopened) {
    // Run what do you want to do only once.

    // To avoid onCreate() if it will be called a second time,
    // so put the boolean to true
    isActivityReopened = true;
 }
}
```